# Как узнать,какой из radiobutton включен в GroupBox?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qradiobutton, qgroupbox, qbuttongroup

У меня есть `QGroupBox` и в нем несколько `QRadioButton`.

Как я могу вывести название включенного `QRadioButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлю к предыдущему ответу:

**QGroupBox** - предоставляет контейнер **для визуализации виджетов** внутри себя.

**QButtonGroup** - предоставляет абстрактный контейнер, 
в который могут быть помещены виджеты кнопок. 
Он не предоставляет визуальное представление этого контейнера 
(см. QGroupBox для виджета контейнера), 
но вместо этого **управляет состояниями каждой из кнопок в группе**.

И пример, где присутствует и QGroupBox и QButtonGroup:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.lblLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumHeight(100)
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Напишите здесь свой текст")
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.editingFinished)

        # --- Horizontal Alignment --- 
        self.groupBox3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Horizontal Alignment.") 
        self.rbHAlignLeft = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Qt.AlignLeft", self.groupBox3) 
        self.rbHAlignLeft.setChecked(True)
        self.rbHAlignRight = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Qt.AlignRight", self.groupBox3)   
        self.rbHAlignHCenter = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Qt.AlignHCenter", self.groupBox3)
        self.rbHAlignJustify = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Qt.AlignJustify", self.groupBox3)
        self.hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox3)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rbHAlignLeft)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rbHAlignRight)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rbHAlignHCenter)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rbHAlignJustify)        

        # --- Vertical Alignment --- 
        self.groupBox4 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Vertical Alignment.") 
        self.rbVAlignTop = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Qt.AlignTop", self.groupBox4) 
        self.rbVAlignBottom = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Qt.AlignBottom", self.groupBox4)   
        self.rbVAlignVCenter = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Qt.AlignVCenter", self.groupBox4)
        self.rbVAlignVCenter.setChecked(True)        
        self.hLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox4)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rbVAlignTop)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rbVAlignBottom)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.rbVAlignVCenter)

        # --- Выравнивание в обоих направлениях ---
        self.groupBox5 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Выравнивание в обоих направлениях.")
        self.chk_center = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Qt.AlignCenter", self.groupBox5)         
        self.chk_center.stateChanged.connect(self.chk_center_state_changed)   
        self.vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.groupBox5)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.chk_center)   

        self.label = QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""QLabel {
                                    font-weight: bold;
                                    font-size: 20px;
                                    color: gray;
                                    }
                                """)

        # - QGridLayout
        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lblLineEdit, 0, 0, 1, 2)         
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 2)   
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox3, 3, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox4, 4, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox5, 3, 1, 2, 1)        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 6, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addItem(QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding), 12, 0, 1, 2)       


        # --- button group Horizontal Alignment ---
        self.groupHAlignment = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.groupHAlignment.addButton(self.rbHAlignLeft, Qt.AlignLeft)     
        self.groupHAlignment.addButton(self.rbHAlignRight, Qt.AlignRight) 
        self.groupHAlignment.addButton(self.rbHAlignHCenter, Qt.AlignHCenter) 
        self.groupHAlignment.addButton(self.rbHAlignJustify, Qt.AlignJustify)  
        self.groupHAlignment.buttonClicked['int'].connect(self.groupHAlignmentClicked)        

        # --- button group Vertical Alignment ---
        self.groupVAlignment = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.groupVAlignment.addButton(self.rbVAlignTop, Qt.AlignTop)     
        self.groupVAlignment.addButton(self.rbVAlignBottom, Qt.AlignBottom) 
        self.groupVAlignment.addButton(self.rbVAlignVCenter, Qt.AlignVCenter) 
        self.groupVAlignment.buttonClicked['int'].connect(self.groupHAlignmentClicked)   



    def editingFinished(self):
        self.lblLineEdit.setText(self.lineEdit.text())   


    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def groupHAlignmentClicked(self, id_):
        """ Обновляет выравнивание виджета QLineEdit 'lineEdit' 
        и обновляет виджет QCheckBox 'chk_center'  """

        self.label.setText(self.sender().checkedButton().text())

        self.update_alignment()
        self.update_chk_center()     

    @property
    def h_alignment(self):
        """
        Returns the selected horizontal alignment
        """
        return Qt.Alignment(self.groupHAlignment.checkedId())

    # 'vertical alignment' property
    @property
    def v_alignment(self):
        """
        Returns the selected vertical alignment
        """
        return Qt.Alignment(self.groupVAlignment.checkedId())       

    # 'alignment in both directions' property
    @property
    def alignment(self):
        """
        Returns the selected alignments in both directions
        """
        return self.h_alignment | self.v_alignment                  

    def update_alignment(self):
        """ Обновляет выравнивание виджета QLineEdit 'lineEdit'  
        """
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(self.alignment)

    def update_chk_center(self):
        """ Обновляет виджет QCheckBox 'chk_center'
        """
        if self.alignment == Qt.AlignCenter:
            self.chk_center.setChecked(True)
        else:
            self.chk_center.setChecked(False)        

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def chk_center_state_changed(self, state):
        """ Если выбран виджет QCheckBox 'chk_center', 
          автоматически выберите виджеты QRadioButton 'rb_hcenter' и 'rb_vcenter' 
          и обновите выравнивание виджета QLineEdit 'edt_text'
        """
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.rbHAlignHCenter.setChecked(True)     # rb_hcenter
            self.rbVAlignVCenter.setChecked(True)     # rb_vcenter
            self.update_alignment()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 - GroupBox-radiobutton")
    w.resize(700, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Создаёте экземпляр класса `QButtonGroup` и с помощью его метода `addButton` добавляете все необходимые `QRadioButton`'ы в группу. Для получения экземпляра выбранного виджета из этой группы используйте метод `checkedButton` вышеуказанного  класса.